# mutable default value in python

Tags: python

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, stuff = []):
        print(stuff)
        self.stuff = stuff
    def add(self,x):
        self.stuff.append(x)


>>>f = Foo()
[]
>>>f.add(1)
>>>g = Foo()
[1]
```

And I make only one change to the code(line 4)

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, stuff = []):
        print(stuff)
        self.stuff = stuff or []
    def add(self,x):
        self.stuff.append(x)


>>>f = Foo()
[]
>>>f.add(1)
>>>g = Foo()
[]
```

I change something in the line 4 but resulting in the change in the printing outcome(which is in the line 3)

I just want to know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
def __init__(self, stuff = []):
```

all instances created with `Foo()` will use **the same list**, created as the default value for **all** calls of `__init__`. That's why in the first example adding anything to `f` results in modifying the default list for **all** further instance of `Foo`. This is because the part `stuff = []` is evaluated when the interpreter evaluates the `def` line. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function):

> Default parameter values are evaluated when the function **definition** is executed. This means that the expression is evaluated once, when the function is defined, and that the same “pre-computed” value is used for each call.

(bold added by me).

In the second example, as the default is always empty the second part of the `or` clause is evaluated which creates a new, individual instance of a list each time a new instance of `Foo` is created. So all `Foo` instances will have their own lists.

[Here](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) you can find more explanations and examples.

Answer (score 1):

The list you pass as fallback parameter value is instantiated once and reused throughout every call to `__init__`. So adding a value into it will propagate to every next instance of `Foo`.

The difference between the first and second examples is `stuff or []`. You need to know that an *empty* list, when evaluated as a boolean value is `False`, so the `stuff or []` expression returns the second operand if `stuff` is empty, which will always be the case in your example. The second operand is a list that gets instantiated in the method call, so is a different instance everytime `__init__` is called. This ensures that the added value doesn't propagate.